# Parallax image gallery vertical

Tags: slider, parallax

How to create a parallax image gallery,listing all the image in vertical order and  clicking on the current image moves to the second image .

I found a link http://www.hardgraft.com/collections/all/products/classicfolio-heritage
please help me to do as in the above link...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some help on how to create websites like that, you may want to look at this list of parallax tutorials:

http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials/

jQuery seems to be a really popular framework for making parallax websites, but the Skrollr.js website (http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) looks really neat too.

Hope this helps.